# Why accessing structure members inside a function causes malloc(): corrupted top size in C language?

Tags: c, struct, malloc, coredump

I am studying how structures works in C language, and how they can be passed and used inside a function. I don't fully understand the behavior of structures objects and the way how to initialize them using memory allocation with malloc function.

I defined a structure called fARRAY and other parameters as follow:

```
float m = 0.98;
float K = 360.0;
typedef structu {
    float* array;
    size_t len;
} fARRAY;
// functions prototypes
fARRAY operation1(float, float, fARRAY);
fARRAY operation2(fARRAY);
```

Then, I wan to use this structure to store an array of float data type and its length in size_t data type. Then I also want to pass it to functions called operation1 and operation2 as follow:

```
// Function definition. S is the structure, which I will define latter
fARRAY operation1(float m, float K, fARRAY S) {
        fARRAY R = {(float*)malloc(sizeof(S.len)), S.len};
        for(int i = 0; i < R.len; i++) {
                R.array[i] = m * (S.array[i] / (K + S.array[i]));
        }
        return R;
}
fARRAY operation2(fARRAY A) {
        printf("Here inside operation2\n");
        printf("Length of A array: %d", A.len);
        fARRAY iA = {(float*)malloc(sizeof(A.len)), A.len};
        for(int i = 0; i < iA.len; i++) {
            iA.array[i] = 1 / A.array[i];
        }
        return iA;
}
```

After functions definition I wrote the main function as follow:

```
int main() {
        float a[] = {50, 100, 150, 200, 400};
        size_t len = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
        fARRAY S = {a, len};
        fARRAY MIUS = operation1(m, K, S);
        printf("Print MIUS array\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < MIUS.len; i++) {
                printf("%f ", MIUS.array[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        fARRAY iS = operation2(S);
        printf("Printing iS array\n");
        return 0;
}
```

The code was successfully compiled with GNU C Compiler version 8. I did not compiled it with additional flags. And the following, is the error output I obtained.

> Print MIUS array
>
> 0.119512 0.213043 0.288235 0.350000 0.515790
>
> Here inside operation2
>
> malloc(): corrupted top size
>
> Aborted (core dumped)

Analysis of this situation.
Error comes after operation2 prints to screen the phrase "Here inside operation 2", That means error could be arise due to accessing fARRAY iA member len. I think it could cause a core dump, but there is also a corrupted top size error in malloc function. My question is: Why did operation1 work pretty fine and at operation2 raised the error? Despite the fact that both function definitions are very similar.

Comment: malloc-ing sizeof(A.len) looks wrong.  Do you want A.len * sizeof(float) instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your malloc is not valid.

```
    fARRAY R = {(float*)malloc(sizeof(S.len)), S.len};
```

You malloc an array of float there you should malloc like that :

```
    fARRAY R = {(float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * S.len), S.len};
```

You want to have enough space for S.len float in your array so S.len times the size of a float.

Comment: Note: cast  `(float*)` not needed.